# Tensorflow load graph into specific scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm loading a pretrained network into Tensorflow using the methods below that are within a `Network` class (hence the calls to self.xyz). First, `define_network()` is called, then I do initialization of other variables and optimizers, then `load_model()` is called.

However, despite using `tf.variable_scope(self.name)` the variables from the graph are loaded into the generic space of variables. This is problematic as I have two instances of this class that each load the same network and I want to separate the out into different scopes.

How can I load the variables into a specific scope?

P.S. Feel free to correct me on any errors in my code!

```
  def load_model(self):
    with tf.variable_scope(self.name) as scope:
      self.saver.restore(self.sess, self.model_path)
      print("Loaded model from {}".format(self.model_path))

  def define_model(self):   

    with tf.variable_scope(self.name) as scope:
      self.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.model_path + '.meta')
      print("Loaded model from {}".format(self.model_path + '.meta'))
      graph = tf.get_default_graph()

      self.inputs = []
      inp_names = ['i_hand1:0', 'i_hand2:0', 'i_flop1:0', 'i_flop2:0', 'i_flop3:0',
                   'i_turn:0', 'i_river:0', 'i_other:0', 'i_allowed_mod:0', 'keras_learning_phase:0']
      for inp in inp_names:
        self.inputs.append(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(inp))

      self.outputs = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Tanh:0") 
      self.add_output_conversions()

      all_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
      for var in all_vars:
        self.var[var.name] = var
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved by adding an argument into

```
self.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.model_path + '.meta', 'import_scope'=self.name)
```

Here's the [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/exporting_and_importing_meta_graphs#import_meta_graph)

Comment: I've tried that, but I didn't work. It failed with an error. I think this argument is related to how the graph was saved rather than what the new scope should be.